# Login surface does not see the new JSON datas

Tags: php, html, json

I have got the following problem. It is a simple login and reg surface.
Register:

```
<form method="post">
                Username :
                <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
                <br>
                E-mail :
                <input type="text"  name="email" placeholder="E-mail ">
                <br>
                Password :
                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                <br>


                <?php
                if (isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password']) && isset($_POST['username'])) {
                    $allDatas = json_decode(file_get_contents('data.json'), true);
                    $username = $_POST['username'];
                    $password = $_POST['password'];
                    $email = $_POST['email'];
                    $foundUser = false;
                    $valid = false;

                    //check the values
                    if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
                        ?> <font size="1px"><?php echo "Email is required !"; ?> </font><?php
                    } else {
                        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                            ?> <font size="1px"><?php echo "Invalid email format!"; ?> </font><?php
                        }
                    }
                    if (empty($_POST["password"])) {
                        ?> <br><font size="1px"><?php echo "Password is required !"; ?> </font><?php
                    }
                    if (empty($_POST["username"])) {
                        ?> <br><font size="1px"><?php echo "Username is required !"; ?> </font><?php
                    }



                    //is it exists
                    foreach ($allDatas as $value) {
                        if ($value[0] == $username) {
                            ?> <br><font size="1px"><?php echo "Username exists!"; ?> </font><?php
                            $foundUser = true;
                            break;
                        } elseif ($value[2] == $email) {
                            ?> <br><font size="1px"><?php echo "E-Mail registered!";?> </font><br><?php
                            $foundUser = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    //add to database
                    if(!empty($_POST["password"]) && !empty($_POST["username"])&& !empty($_POST["email"]) && filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){$valid = true;}
                    if (!$foundUser && $valid) {
                        $allDatas[] = array($username, $email, $password);
                        file_put_contents('data.json', json_encode($allDatas));
                        echo "Done";
                    }
                    unset($allDatas);
                }
                ?>
                <br>
                <input type="submit" value="Registration">
            </form>
            <br>
            <form action="index.php">
                <input type="submit" name="back" value="Back">
            </form>
```

and the login:

```
<form method="post">
                    Email:
                    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email">
                    <br>
                    Password:
                    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                    <br>

                     <?php
                     $allDatas = json_decode(file_get_contents('data.json'), true);
                     $foundUser = false;
                     $action = "login.php";

                     if (isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password']) ) {
                         $password = $_POST['password'];
                         $email = $_POST["email"];
                         if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
                             ?> <font size="1px"><?php echo "Email is required !"; ?> </font><?php
                         } else {
                             if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                                 ?> <font size="1px"><?php echo "Invalid email format!"; ?> </font><?php
                             }
                         }
                         if (empty($_POST["password"])) {
                             ?> <br><font size="1px"><?php echo "Password is required !"; ?> </font><?php
                         }
                         foreach ($allDatas as $value) {
                             if ($value[2] == $email && $value[1] == $password) {
                                 $foundUser = true;
                                 $username = $value[0];
                                 ?> <font size="1px"><?php echo "Success! Welcome ", $username, " !"; ?> </font><?php
                                 $action = "reddragon.html";
                             }
                         }
                     }
                     if(!$foundUser)
                     {
                         ?><br> <font size="1px"><?php echo "Please type your datas!"; ?> </font><?php
                     }
                     ?>

                     <br>
                        <input type="submit" value="Log in">
                     <br>
                </form>
                <font color="red" size="1px">Before you play, LOG IN!</font>
                <form action="<?php echo "$action";?>">
                    <input type="submit" name="play" value="Play">
                </form>
                <form action="index.php">
                    <input type="submit" name="back" value="Back">
                </form>
```

My problem is that, when I add a new member (username, psw, mail), it will be added to the JSON database, but the login surface does not see it! The old ones are ok, but the new one, that I've created by registration is not accepted by the login.

What can be the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

flip `$email` and `$password` on line #54 of `register.php` as follows:

```
$allDatas[] = array($username, $password, $email);
```